# Draw a border around an oval CAShapeLayer on MacOS

Tags: objective-c, macos, io, core-graphics

I need to display an oval layer with a predefined fillColor and a 1px borderColor.
**Here is code:**

```
    CGRect r = CGRectMake(28, self.bounds.size.height - 5 - 12, 12.0, 12.0);
    NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:r];

    NSColor *fillColor = [NSColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:193.0/255.0 blue:47.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
    NSColor *borderColor = [NSColor colorWithRed:226.0/255.0 green:70.0/255.0 blue:84.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];

    minimizeButtonLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    minimizeButtonLayer.path = path.CGPath;
    minimizeButtonLayer.fillColor = fillColor.CGColor;
    minimizeButtonLayer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
    minimizeButtonLayer.borderWidth = 1.0;
```

The oval shape is correctly displayed but without any border.
Why? Please help me.

P.S. Please note that path.CGPath is from a NSBezierPath category.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by replacing borderColor with strokeColor

```
minimizeButtonLayer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
```

with

```
minimizeButtonLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.CGColor;
```